# Can a UITextView through IB be assigned a variable name?

Tags: objective-c, ios, uitextview

I am working on an app that has multiple `UITextView`s with a custom keyboard and then some custom menu options that will insert predefined text.  Is there a way to use a variable for a `UITextView`?

The code below works great but I need to use the custom keyboard/buttons for more than just one `UITextView`.

```
- (IBAction)textBTN:(id)sender {
    textView1.text = [textView1.text stringByAppendingString:@"myAsciiString"];
}
```

I will also have `textView2`, `textView3`, etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add your text fields into an array and modify their properties in a loop:

```
NSArray *textViews= [NSArray arrayWithObjects:textView1, textView2, textView3, nil];
for(UITextView *txtView in textViews)
   txtView.text = [txtView.text stringByAppendingString:@"myAsciiString"];

[textViews release];
```

**Edit**

If you wish to know which textView initiated the action (assuming you connected multiple textViews to the same IBAction), you could either set and check the tag of the view, or you can compare with an instance:

```
textView1.tag = 0;
textView2.tag = 1;
textView3.tag = 2;
//etc.

- (IBAction)someTextViewAction:(id)sender {
    //Option 1
    if (sender.tag == 0)
       textView1.text = [textView1.text stringByAppendingString:@"myAsciiString"];
    else if(sender.tag == 1)
       textView2.text = [textView2.text stringByAppendingString:@"myAsciiString"];
    else if(sender.tag == 2)
       textView3.text = [textView3.text stringByAppendingString:@"myAsciiString"];

    //Option 2
    if ([sender isEqual:textView1])
       textView1.text = [textView1.text stringByAppendingString:@"myAsciiString"];
    else if ([sender isEqual:textView2])
       textView2.text = [textView2.text stringByAppendingString:@"myAsciiString"];
    else if ([sender isEqual:textView3])
       textView3.text = [textView3.text stringByAppendingString:@"myAsciiString"];

}
```

If you wish to assign a value to the active text view, you could iterate through your subviews and if it has first responder, set the value:

```
- (IBAction)someButtonAction:(id)sender {

    for (UIView *view in self.subviews)
    {
            if ([view isKindOfClass:[UITextView class]])
            {
                if ([view isFirstResponder])
                {
                        view.text = [view.text stringByAppendingString:@"myAsciiString"];
                }
            }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply however this will add my text value to all the views at the same time.  Maybe I should have phrased my question a little different.

I would like to be able to know which UITextView was tapped for editing and use the IBAction listed above to insert the text "Only in the active text view", not insert in all of them.  Thanks again!

Comment: Updated to reflect your comment.

Comment: This approach (option 1) still evaluates to true and inserts my text into all text views at the same time.  I have the action wired to one single button in IB that should insert the text based on the active textview.  I appreciate your help but I must be missing something here in your instruction.

Comment: Updated to reflect your comment.

Comment: Thanks for your help Jeremy, I was headed down the path of checking first responder and I saw your latest reply.  I think this will keep me moving along for now.  Thanks for the super fast replies!!!

Comment: You bet!  Another option would be to use my last example, except iterate through an array of your UITextViews...but the key is to check the firstResponder.